# Run Ubuntu 12.04 Without Hard Drive

Tags: installation, 10.04, drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Ubuntu without a hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89241/how-can-i-run-ubuntu-without-a-hard-drive)

Is there any possible way i can run Ubuntu 12.04 from a live USB drive with out having a hard drive in my computer?

The hard drive in my netbook is dead so i decided to make a live USB drive to run it from. When booting the operating system it gets to the stage with the purple screen where it says 'Ubuntu' and the orange dots move across. This is where it is searching for the hard drive, but because there isn't one it won't proceed with the installation.

This is a netbook remember, and so i can't use an Ubuntu boot disc as there is no CD drive either.

Hope you lot will be able to help as i am really stuck with this.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/89241/47206

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170454/can-i-install-ubuntu-to-my-32-gb-usb-pen-drive/170456#170456

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qbbw6NvOCwU

Answer (score 0):

Ooh... that is a tough one.

I'd recommend, if you have any friends with Ubuntu, to visit them and ask them, in your nicest voice, to please make you a startup USB drive.

Or, if the computer you're using to post this question is an Ubuntu machine, then download the .iso of the release you want, and then open "Startup Disk Creator" and use *that* to 'burn' the Live USB. (I think it might do something slightly differently with the Startup Disk Creator, as opposed to merely extracting the files to a USB stick.)
I'd recommend getting an empty flash drive / USB stick, and setting *all* available space to be used for "changes." I believe that the "changes" include settings changed, files downloaded, and programs that you installed.

The key is: use the Startup Disk Creator utility, with the "Erase Drive" options instead of merely unzipping the .iso to a USB stick.

Tell me if you have any luck, or if you still have problems.